# Why is Sinon returning incorrect number of calls on the "then" method of the promise in jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, sinon

I am using angularjs, jasmine and sinon. I am trying to work with promises to see if I can stub them correctly. In the test below, "then" method will not be called until $rootScope.$apply is called, yet sinon is reporting it as being called. I can see it because local var "thenCalled" is not set to true. What is going on?

```
describe("$q promises ", function () {

    var client;

    var $q, $rootScope;      

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(function () {

        inject(function ($injector) {
            $q = $injector.get('$q');
            $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
        });

        client = {
            // Classic async method which returns an un-resolved promise.
            fetchAsync: function () {                   

                var dfd = $q.defer();

                // This contrived example isn't the important bit, replace this
                // with a jQuery.get call, or any other async action which yeilds
                // a promise to the caller.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    debugger;
                    dfd.resolve("Response");

                    // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                }, 1500);

                return dfd.promise;
            },

            // Slightly different take, this time a Promise resolver is supplied
            // to the method.
            asyncInit: function (completionPromise) {

                // Again, the implementation isn't important - but after an async
                // delay this method will either resolve, or reject the supplied
                // connection promise.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    completionPromise.resolve("I'm done!");
                    // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                }, 1500);

                // Note the lack of return statement.
            }
        };
    });

it("Stub a promise so the testcase has control over it", function () {

        // Sometimes you want the testcase to hold onto the Promise so you can 
        // assert the state of other parts of the system while the Promise is
        // still un-resolved.  Start by creating a new Promise.
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        var fetchPromise = dfd.promise;

        var fetchPromiseSpy = sinon.spy(fetchPromise, 'then');

        // Now stub fetchAsync so it returns this Promise.
        sinon.stub(client, 'fetchAsync').returns(fetchPromise);

        // Some example state, just to show we have control over the Promise.
        var didWeResolveThePromiseYet = false;

        var thenCalled = false;
        // Call the method, but it won't have resolved yet...
        client.fetchAsync().then(function () {
            thenCalled = true;
            expect(didWeResolveThePromiseYet).toBe(true);
            console.log("Test case dictated when the Promise resolves");
        });

        // Ok, now let's flip that flag.
        didWeResolveThePromiseYet = true;

        // ... and resolve the promise.
        dfd.resolve("Go for it!");
        //$rootScope.$apply(); //<-- this is mandatory, promise will not resolve and call then until you do this

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(client.fetchAsync);
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(fetchPromiseSpy);
        expect(thenCalled).toBe(true);
    });

 function fullyResolvedPromise(valueToResolve) {
        var dfd = $q.defer();

        dfd.resolve(valueToResolve);
        $rootScope.$apply();

        return dfd.promise;
    }

    function rejectedPromise(error) {
        var dfd = $q.defer();

        dfd.reject(error);
        $rootScope.$apply();

        return dfd.promise;
    }
});
```